# Как правильно наложить альфа-канал в OpenGL ES2?

Tags: java, android, opengles

Изучаю OpenGL ES 2 по книге. Прочёл глава о текстурировании. Написал пробную программу и вывел на экран треугольник с текстурой. Текстура в файле png.

```
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inScaled = false;
    final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), resourceId, options);
    texImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);
```

Всё работает нормально.
Решил попробовать использовать текстуру с альфа-каналом. В фотошопе сделал сделал png с альфой. Сохранил. Наложил текстуру на треугольник. Вместо прозрачности получил чёрные пиксели. Подскажите, как правильно накладывать текстуру на поверхность, чтобы альфа-канал работал правильно и был прозрачным, а не чёрным?

Comment: https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es1.1/xhtml/glAlphaFunc.xml

Comment: Читайте про блендинг.